# Telerik MVC upload control disappear

Tags: asp.net-mvc, file-upload, telerik, telerik-mvc

I have a problem with disappearing telerik upload control (mvc).
I have basic template project with one telerik upload control on page - nothing more.

Scenario:

1. Selecting file to upload
2. File appeared in div with uploaded files
3. I click remove button to delete uploaded file
4. Upload control disappear and it's removed from DOM

This occurs only in Chrome (ver. 26.0.1410.43 m). On FF and IE works fine.
Any solution?

Comment: Any errors in JS console of Chrome?

Comment: There are no js errors

Comment: new info: I have downgraded my Chrome to Version 23.0.1271.91 m and upload works fine. It seems like some chrome changes make this error.

Answer (score 0):

I come across the same issue, the reason is that the remove function in teleric js will remove the whole content in upload container, over write the function to handle this issue.

Comment: Environment: Chrome 35 jquery 1.51